# Laravel merge 2 collection with paginator

Tags: php, laravel

I need to do paging with two different collection. Have priority listing. Money that is placed in the priority list.

Why do not you do a single query, you can say the priority list. Reason, when using filtering; city, county, category I choose. However, the site owner, having priority listing in the city, county, or even in one of the priority areas listed in the category you want.

So in a query keywords when using 3 criteria, other criteria will be enough in the first. Each page lists 20 records, if the primary listing of the 30 first listing, the second collection of records in the other I would like to be listed thereafter.

According to the criteria normally be with you now I share my code. Waiting for your suggestions. Thank you in advance.

I'm sorry for my bad english.

```
DB::table('UserAds')
        ->join('Ads', 'Ads.id', '=', 'UserAds.ad_id')
        ->join('Users', 'Users.id', '=', 'UserAds.user_id')
        ->join('AdCategory', 'AdCategory.ad_id', '=', 'Ads.id')
        ->join('AdEducationPrices', 'AdEducationPrices.ad_id', '=', 'Ads.id')
        ->join('City', 'City.id', '=', 'Ads.city_id')
        ->join('Town', 'Town.id', '=', 'Ads.town_id')
        ->leftJoin('AdMedias', 'AdMedias.ad_id', '=', 'Ads.id')
        ->select('Ads.*', 'AdEducationPrices.*', 'City.name as city_name', 'City.id as city_id',
                                    'Town.name as town_name', 'Town.id as town_id', 'AdMedias.url')
        ->where('Ads.is_publish', 1)
        ->whereIn('AdCategory.category_id', $new_category_array)
        ->where('Ads.city_id', $city_id)
        ->where('Ads.town_id', $town_id)
        ->where('UserAds.is_purchased', true)
        ->where('UserAds.started_at', '<', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->where('UserAds.finished_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->where('AdMedias.type', 'picture')
        ->groupby('UserAds.ad_id')->orderby('finished_at', 'DESC')
        ->orderby('started_at', 'DESC')->paginate(20);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `array_merge` for 2 queries. And filtered records for paginator. Ty for reading my question. I hope to help someone

```
$new_collection = array_merge($Priority, $Ads);
$new_collection_count = count($new_collection);

$perPage = 20;
$currentPage = Input::get('page', 1) - 1;
$new_collection = array_slice($new_collection, $currentPage * $perPage, $perPage);
$Ads = Paginator::make($new_collection, $new_collection_count, $perPage);
```